# Where do I have to place the default config for gcloud storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, strapi

Im trying to use google-storage in my strapi backend. I was able to choose [the provider to upload files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-upload-gcloud-storage) to but when ever I try to upload a file I get an error:

> Could not authenticate request Unexpected error while acquiring
>   application default credentials: Could not load the default
>   credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

It said something about default credentials but where do I have to place them and in which format?

Answer (score 0):

You need the credentials for access to your project, the credentials are in json file, you can obtain this Json from google console, the info to create a json file is here. [Creating a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account)

After obtain your json, you need to check the documentation for strapi plugin in order to connect to google cloud storage using a json file. [upload gcloud storage plugin for strapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-upload-gcloud-storage)